# passing another class (files) value from view to controller directly from ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net

FunwarsVM.cs

```
public class FunwarsVM : IFunwars
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string OurTeam { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Opponent { get; set; }
    public string Score { get; set; }
    public int FileID { get; set; }

    public List<Funwars> Funwars { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public  ImageUpload Files { get; set; }

    public FunwarsVM()  
    {
        this.Funwars = new List<Funwars>();
        this.Files = new ImageUpload();
    }
}
```

ImageUpload.cs

```
public class ImageUpload
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MimeType { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }


    [NotMapped]
    public List<IFormFile> Images { get; set; }
}
```

View (only image upload part)

```
<form id="holder" method="post" action="/Funwars/Add" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form-group">

        <h3>Screenshots</h3>

        <input type="file" name="files.images" value="@Model.Files.Images" multiple />

    </div>       
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(FunwarsVM model)
{

    model.Add();
    return RedirectToAction("Index",model);
}
```

So guys, I want to pass Image files from view to controller. When I am passing `@Model.Files.Images` in my view, it means I am passing `List<IFormFile>` to my model, but it passes `null`!

but when I add

```
public List<IFormFile> Images { get; set;}
```

directly to my FunwarsVM, and then pass `@Model.Images` to my View, it returns right pictures I am adding!

why won't it work when I am calling that `List<IFormFile>` object from my View by after I create instance of `ImageUpload` model, but when i am calling directly it works!?

Comment: Did you ensure you are setting the form attribute enctype="multipart/form-data"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean

Comment: yes sir, i have added that to my form!

Comment: Can you post your controller code?  Your auto binding might not be defined correctly.

Comment: @bdparrish done sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reason ASP.NET Core doesn't bind file to a nested object if you pass only one property for it (`Images` in your case). So the solution is just add any other property of that class to view

```
<input type="hidden" name="files.id" />
<input type="file" name="files.images" value="@Model.Files.Images" multiple />
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your controller action only has the `FunwarsVM` model in the parameters, then it will never be binded correctly unless it is part of `FunwarsVM` object, which is why it works when you utilize the model.

if you add a new parameter `List<IFormFile> images`, then it should work as expected.  Don't quote me on the way to define the parameter, but I believe it needs to have the same name as the `name` attribute to get automatically binded.

### EDIT

Add the second parameter so that there is something to bind it to.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(FunwarsVM model, List<IFormFile> images)
{
    model.Add();
    return RedirectToAction("Index",model);
}
```

Comment: Sir, i also fixed that name attribute and tried on that way but it doesn't affect, well, thank you for information, but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: did you add the second parameter to your Action?

Comment: so,as i got,  i can't pass that value only within my FunwarsVM?

Comment: yes i know what you meant sir, but i am looking for answers about passing those values using only one model

Comment: Just create a new class as the viewmodel, but you said you didn't want to use a view model